# Render HTML to String in Spring MVC with mocked request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have written the following method that returns string with rendered HTML of the view:

```
public String getViewAsString(String viewName, Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request) {
   View view = this.viewResolver.resolveViewName(viewName, Locale.US);
   MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
   view.render(model, request, response);
   return response.getContentAsString();
}
```

It works correctly in the application.

In my test class, I provide an instance of `MockHttpServletRequest` as the `request` parameter:

```
String html = getViewAsString("someView", model, new MockHttpServletRequest());
```

In this case, the retured value of `html` is empty string. Why?

Comment: Why? WHat is it the purpose of this method? Looks like you are working around Spring MVC.

Comment: @M.Deinum I would like to render a number of pages, zip them together and allow user to download the whole package.

Comment: You shouldn't use the `MockHttpServletResponse` for that as that is designed for testing not for production use. If you want that find another way but don't use test classes for that.